# Using If statement in mysql batch script without making a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How can below Sql server statement be converted to Mysql. Without making it a Stored Procedure. we are migrating Sql queries to Mysql.

**SQL SERVER 1**

```
IF (@val = true)
BEGIN
    Insert into custom_report values (1,2,3);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Insert into custom_report values (4,5,6);
END;
```

**SQL SERVER 2**

```
IF (@val = true)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM custom_report WHERE is_active = 1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM custom_report WHERE is_active = 0;
END;
```

Comment: Because you tagged MySQL and SQL server i have a feeling you are mixing MySQL and SQL server syntax.. Because it looks like you are trying to executes SQL server syntax in a MySQL server..

Comment: we are migrating sql queries to mysql. @RaymondNijland

Comment: i assume `{0}` is a "variable" here because it's not valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: @RaymondNijland there is a saying in south asia, Do not try to pull the skin of the hair. can you do Plus to this Q.

Comment: i geuss you meant check mine question update.. well you can also check mine answer update because it also supports the sql server 1 and sql server 2 parts now.

Answer (score 1):

You can test `@` in the query itself, you don't need an `IF` statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM custom_report
WHERE is_active = @val
```

I'm assuming that the value of `@val` is `1` or `0`, since you're comparing it with `true`, which is the same as `1`.

In the `INSERT` statement you can use conditionals in the values:

```
INSERT INTO custom_report
VALUES (IF(@val, 1, 4), IF(@val, 2, 5), IF(@val, 3, 6));
```

Comment: @abksharma Keep in mind that the variable "`{0}`" needs to be a 1, 0, true or false otherwise the autocasting will not handle the checking correctly.

Comment: Good point. In which case the comparison isn't really needed at all, we can just compare it directly with `is_active`.

Comment: @barmar thanks, but the question has an underlying argument that you can not use IF in mysql batch statement. Like we do in SQL Server easily.

Comment: True, but in many cases you can use conditional expressions instead of IF statements. I've added the solution for the `INSERT` that shows how you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also rewrite that SQL Server query syntax in these MySQL queries syntax.

Keep in mind that the variable needs to be a `1`, `0`, `true` or `false`
 otherwise the autocasting will not handle the checking correctly.

**SQL SERVER 1**

Using `IF` statement

```
SET @variable = <variable>;

INSERT INTO
 custom_report 
(<columns>) # is less error prone when defining
VALUES(
     IF(@variable = true, 1, 4)
   , IF(@variable = true, 2, 5)
   , IF(@variable = true, 3, 6)
)
```

Using `CASE END` statement

```
SET @variable = <variable>;

INSERT INTO
 custom_report 
(<columns>) # is less error prone when defining
VALUES(
     (
       CASE
         WHEN @variable = true
         THEN 1
         ELSE 4
       END
     )
   , (
       CASE
        WHEN @variable = true
        THEN 2
        ELSE 5  
       END
     )
   , (
       CASE
         WHEN @variable = true
         THEN 3
         ELSE 6
       END
     )
)
```

**SQL SERVER 2**

Using `IF` statement

```
SET @variable = <variable>;

SELECT 
 *
FROM 
  custom_report
WHERE
 is_active = IF(@variable = true, 1, 0)
```

Using `CASE END` statement

```
SET @variable = <variable>;

SELECT 
 *
FROM 
  custom_report
WHERE
 is_active = 
   CASE
     WHEN @variable = true
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
   END
```

Comment: What happened to the `is_active` column in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You're either selecting all rows or no rows, depending on the variable.

Comment: "You're either selecting all rows or no rows, depending on the variable" Yes indeed true @Barmar forgotten the `is_active =` part in the SQL

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Statment for above will be as below. Using "If"

```
set @val = {0};
set @query1 = if(@val = true,'select * from  custom_report where is_active =1 ','select * from custom_report where is_active =0');
SET @stmt_str =  @query1;
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_str;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: You can only use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` in a stored procedure.

Comment: "You can only use PREPARE and EXECUTE in a stored procedure" No @Barmar you can use them outside stored procedures also..Check the demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2RzagQ6FpwjJg37YKJwoG/1 or the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html